# Simplyfying codes in NodeJS MVC

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport and trying to do my code organisation like routes(just one line route), controller with one method to handle route, model to do some action which coming from controller method. Following code is working fine returning me token if mobile number and password is matched. But how can I reorgnize code so it break and become properly, I dont' want to put anything in routes.js file but just one single line, and nothing in controller but one method where I want to put all passport stuff in passport.js file either config/passport.js or root/passport.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  compression = require('compression'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  passport = require('passport')
const app = express()
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use('/', Router)
```

Now in my `config/routes.js` file

```
const passport = require('passport')
const userController = require('../app/controllers/users_controller')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({mobile: username}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err)
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username'})
      }
      console.log(` Password: ${password} `)
      if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'})
      }
      return done(null, user)
    })
  })
)

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err)
    }
    cb(null, user)
  })
})

router.post('/api/v1/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Something is not right',
        user: user,
      })
    }

    req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(` Error: ${err}`)
      }
      // generate a signed son web token wtih contents of user
      const token = jwt.sign(user.id, 'your_jwt_secret')
      return res.json({user, token})
    })
  })(req, res)
})
```

I want to break it, it should not be in routes, my other routes are like following

```
router.get('/logout', users_controller.update)
router.post('/forgotPassword', users_controller.update)
```

I want to that it should be like following route

```
router.post('/login', users_controller.login)
```

I tried many times but still can't work out, even used this code, but in my another website I used same method and it worked in Controller, so all passport related stuff I put in controller but that one is also not correct, it should be one line in route file and method in controller rest in separate passport.js files.

Kindly can you assist me how can I do it?

Comment: Organize your files around  features / pages / components, not roles. Also, place your test files next to their implementation.

Comment: Look like you may not got my question, it is not React  I am working on NodeJS backend and need to organise structure so routes should be in route, model should be in model and service class in separate files.

Comment: https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/projectstructre/breakintcomponents.md